# Insert values into a new table with "position in group" column?

Tags: sql

I have a table:

```
c1     c2   c3
----------
100    200
100    201
100    203
200    405
200    408
```

...and another table created with 3 columns.

I need to add the values from the above table to new table including a new column like,

```
c1     c2   c3
--------------
100    200   1
100    201   2
100    203   3
200    405   1
200    408   2
```

...and so on. `c3` is dependent on `c1` and when `c1` is changed, it is to be set for 1 and continue to increment.

The second table is created and is empty.
I need to copy values of columns `c1` and `c2` of old table to the new table and at the same time, insert new values to `c3` of second table.

Comment: Is the first table supposed to have `c3` or is that just a typo? And which database are you using?

Comment: no relationship...it is to be populated from the first existing table to the new one...just like migration with new values to c3 added

Comment: INSERT INTO new_table (data) SELECT data FROM old_table; will transfer it over. not sure how to add the value

Comment: For what database, and what have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

```
insert into my_table2
  select c1, c2
        ,row_number() over (partition by c1 order by c1, c2)
    from my_table
```

Comment: Fine for SQL Server, but not all databases support an equivalent to `row_number() over...`

Comment: @pst: PostgreSQL (8.4+) supports window functions and I'm pretty sure Oracle and DB/2 also support them.

Comment: @muistooshort I only need to come up with one counter-example to be correct: enter in ... MySQL [or SQLite]! :-) (In this particular case I think the standard MySQL hacks can be applied.)

Answer (score 2):

This should be what you need:

**Sample schema**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  c1 INT NOT NULL,
  c2 INT NOT NULL
  );

INSERT INTO TEST VALUES
(100, 200), (100, 201), (100, 203), (200, 405), (200, 408)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT T1.C1, T1.C2, COUNT(*) AS C3
FROM test T1
JOIN test T2 ON T1.C1 = T2.C1 AND T1.C2 >= T2.C2
GROUP BY T1.C1, T1.C2
```

Comment: I'm torn on whether I like it or not: it's cool and addresses pst's concern. But on the other hand, cartesian products are  somewhat anathema in the sql world :)

Comment: In pure SQL, I cannot find a better way (but still looking forward to)

Comment: It's good :) I don't know how to do it otherwise, either. Rownums are so useful. The anaylytic row number can be used in Postgresql and Oracle. Oracle has built in rownum. mysql you can fake out rownums. So hopefully it is available on the rdbms in question. But this works.